# How to add gesture to map overlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app stores thousands of latitude, longitude details from CLLocationManager to draw the overlay on the map. Now I wanted to add gesture to that overlay and show out some message when you touch the overlay not anywhere else. Could anyone come up with simple solution for this?

Comment: paste the code what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your overlay is implemented as a view (or is part of a view), you can override the function

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

to test where the user touched the screen.

If the overlay has a bounding rectangle, you can simply compare the user's touch position with the rectangle.  This will tell you whether the touch was inside the overlay or not.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];  
tgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
[tgr release];
```